# Javascript - Stuck in an if statement - Beginner Question

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator, simply my problem is this:

1. Page refreshes.
2. User clicks on any number and the number gets added to the `First Number: nums_clicked` h1.
3. If user clicks on an operator sign`(+ - *)`, the clicked boolean becomes `true`.
4. If clicked is `true`, add the numbers clicked to the `Second Number: nums_clicked`

My problem is even if I click on an operator sign, it keeps adding the numbers I am clicking to the `First Number: nums_clicked` h1, why is that happening? It even happens while clicked is TRUE!

My

```js
let numbers = [];
let first_num = "";
let second_num = "";
let clicked = false;
let result = false;
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  numbers[i] = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].innerText);

}

for (var i = 9; i < 12; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    clicked = true;
  });
}

if (!clicked && !result) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (clicked) {
      break;
    }
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",
      function() {
        console.log("clicked = " + clicked);

        first_num += this.innerText;
        document.getElementById("firstNumber").innerText = "Number1: " + first_num;
      });
  }
}
if (clicked && !result) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",
      function() {

        second_num += this.innerText;
        document.getElementById("secondNumber").innerText = "Number2: " + second_num;
      });
  }
}
document.getElementById("result-btn").addEventListener("click",
  function() {

    result = true;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <button type="button" name="button">1</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">2</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">3</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="button">4</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">5</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">6</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="button">7</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">8</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">9</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="button">+</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">*</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">-</button>
    <br>
    <button id="result-btn" type="button" name="button">Result</button>
    <h1 id="firstNumber">First Number: </h1>
    <h1 id="secondNumber">Second Number: </h1>
    <h1 id="result">Result: </h1>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Code:

Screenshot of index.html (Red part while `clicked=false` and blue part is while `clicked=true`:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have `if (!clicked && !result)` at the top-level of the script. That condition is checked when the page loads, not after the user has clicked on anything, so both will always be true. You should check the conditions in the event listeners.

Comment: As a result, you're adding multiple event listeners to all the buttons, so they do every action when you click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue was that you were never creating the click events for the second number, because those were behind the `if(!result...`.  Like Barmar mentioned, even if you created the click events for the second number, the events from the first number would be triggered also and it would still not work. Also you did not had anything for setting the actual results.

I made some changes on your code to make it simpler to understand, but still trying to follow your logic. Here you go:

```js
let first_num;
let second_num;
let operation;

for (var i = 9; i < 12; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('button')[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    operation = this.innerText;
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('button')[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!operation) {
      document.getElementById('firstNumber').innerText += this.innerText;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('secondNumber').innerText += this.innerText;
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('result-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  first_num = document.getElementById('firstNumber').innerText;
  second_num = document.getElementById('secondNumber').innerText;
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = calculate(
    parseInt(first_num),
    parseInt(second_num),
    operation
  );
});

function calculate(a, b, operation) {
  if (operation === '+') {
    return sum(a, b);
  } else if (operation === '-') {
    return minus(a, b);
  } else if (operation === '*') {
    return multiply(a, b);
  }
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
function minus(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" name="button">1</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">2</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">3</button>
    <br />
    <button type="button" name="button">4</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">5</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">6</button>
    <br />
    <button type="button" name="button">7</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">8</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">9</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" name="button">+</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">*</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">-</button>
    <br />
    <button id="result-btn" type="button" name="button">Result</button>
    <h1>First Number: <span id="firstNumber"></span></h1>
    <h1>Second Number: <span id="secondNumber"></span></h1>
    <h1>Result: <span id="result"></span></h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why use an external stackblitz instead of stack snippet here?

Comment: Hmm I can add the html too right, one sec

Comment: You should also explain what the problem was, and how you resolved it, not just post code.

Comment: I just started answering people one week ago so I am still learning, thanks @Barmar for the tips

Comment: Even if you change the value of the variable " clicked" inside one of the blocks, it won't matter because once it checks the block, it moves on.The condition does not get re-evaluated after the block has been executed. That's just not how the if statement works ij=n js.